# Docker Container's PublicPort via Remote API

Tags: docker

How can I get the publicport from a running container by using the remote api? The information does not seem to be available in list or inspect containers. On creation of the container I allowing Docker to set the publicport randomly due to the large number of containers being spun up.

Thanks much for the thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

It's listed under NetworkSettings in the inspect:

```
curl http://localhost:2375/containers/650eeb3c5d63/json
...
"Ports":{
   "443/tcp":[{"HostIp":"0.0.0.0","HostPort":"32768"}],
   "80/tcp":[{"HostIp":"0.0.0.0","HostPort":"32769"}]}
...

bash$ docker port 650eeb3c5d63
443/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32768
80/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32769
```

Answer (score 0):

if i'm not mistaken its under

```
 "HostConfig": {
            "PortBindings": {
                "3306/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "3309"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
```

Comment: That appears to be the containers/create api call for making a new container, rather than querying the docker assigned port number of a running container.